# Red5 plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, red5

What url do you use for it because http://www.red5.org/projects/red5plugin/update_0.1.x/ gots redirected to http://code.google.com/p/red5/, and my eclipse is heavily complaining about network connection problems (other plugins update correctly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go here for info on the plugin: http://www.red5.org/red5-ide-plugin/

Eclipse 3.2+ Link: http://www.red5.org/downloads/projects/red5plugin/update_0.2.x/

Comment: thnxs for the update, just going nuts looking for info on red5 and only finding dead ends...

Comment: Dominick recently changed a bunch of the content and moved some of it to a new location. We're trying to consolidate it all to make it easy to find stuff.. :)

Comment: http://www.red5.org/red5-ide-plugin/ is the current address. Images are broken though.

Comment: Ok ill let the maintainer know

Comment: And now that address doesn't let me download it either :(

Comment: Yeah we lost a service on the box, I make sure Dominick makes it available elsewhere